# Is it okay to use these kind of batteries with this holder (pictures inside)

Tags: power-supply, nimh

[image]

[image]

I have the pictured battery with 1.2 v .. It does not look like regular AA batteries on both ends.

My questions:

1) Is it fine to put the batteries in the holder although it does not fit (the batteries are slightly shorter than regular AA). So I have to force the ends to touch.

2) I do not know why the holder specifies 1.5 V on each slot. Would it be problematic if I use 1.2?

Battery brand and specifications:

Lucky sky AA NI-MH 1200 mAh 1.2 v (made in china)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use this holder for this battery even though it is not designed for it. The battery holder is designed for AA (or Penlite) batteries. Normal Alkaline batteries are 1.5 V when full so that is why the battery holder states 1.5 V. The battery holder cannot tell the difference between 1.5 V and 1.2 V so you can still use it.

The battery has soldering tabs so it also is not designed to be used in a battery holder. It is designed to make packs of batteries with wires to a connector. Still, you can use it in a battery holder. But since the batteries are slightly shorter than an AA don't be surprised if the connections get loose after a while.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the current you want to draw. Although the cells fit mechanically, those tagged cells, intended to be soldered, are capable of much higher current output than the spring terminals in the battery holder are intended to handle.

If your application is below the fraction of one amp for which the holder is intended, then fine.

If your application is capable of drawing the several amps that those batteries can source, you will probably have problems with the quality and consistency of those spring connections.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK if it does not have mechanical issues. 1.5V is the voltage for regular batteries, this is rechargeable (NiMH) and their voltage is 1.2V. This is not the issue for holder at all.

Please take note that the final voltage would be lower (4x1.2V instead of 4x1.5V). Usually this is not the issue, but check if that voltage is suitable for the device you want to power.

These types of batteries are meant to be soldered on board so this is the reason they have these connectors spot welded on the ends.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if it fits, you're usually fine. That battery looks like it was intended to be soldered into a big pack, but there's no reason you couldn't remove the tabs and put it in a holder. The 1.5V marking has more to do with common naming conventions rather than a specific voltage rating. A lot pf people refer to AAs as 1.5V batteries (mainly because the non-rechargeable ones are ~1.5V). It's really just 1.5V as opposed to a 9V battery or a 6V battery. It's only a connector so if it fits and whatever you want to run is happy with the slightly lower voltage of rechargeable AAs, then you're fine.